# How to document/verify consistent layering?

Tags: design-patterns, documentation, layers

I have recently moved to the dark side: I am now a CUSTOMER of software development -- mainly websites. With this new role comes new concerns.

As a programmer i know how solid an application becomes when it is properly layered, and I want to use this knowledge in my new job. I don't want business logic in my presentation layer, and certainly not presentation stuff in my data layer. Thus, I want to be able to demand from my supllier that they document the level of layering, and how neat and consistent the layering is.

The big question is: How is the level of layering documented to me as a customer, and is that a reasonable demmand for me to have, so I don't have to look in the code (I'm not supposed to do that anymore)?

Comment: Is successful deployment your responsibility?  If so, you better have *someone* in your team look at the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is reasonable - as a customer you can require anything you want, and using good layering as an indication of code quality and separation of concerns is a valid requirement.

There are many tools out there that will help with such documentation - some of them will produce an image of the [Directed Acyclic Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), showing you that the lower down layers are not calling the higher up levels. Some static analysis tools will do so too.

Getting a representation of the DAG is probably what will give you the most idea regarding how layering works in the code base.

In the .NET world, [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) is a good commercial tool that will help with visualizing the high level architecture and layering of anapplication.

Answer (score 2):

You have worked as a programmer, you probably have seen projects fail/take longer than expected and you know that you don't want that as a client.

You have every right to demand such a thing.

What I would suggest is apart from documenting the layers of the application have them run their unit/intergration tests in front of you.

How they organize their tests will tell you more about the code than just the documentation and you won't even have to see it.